# Non-unital Russo-Dye Theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, positivity

Let $A$ be  a C$^*$-algebra and let $\phi$ be a positive linear map from $A$ to $B(H)$ (bounded linear operators on Hilbert's
space).  If $A$ is unital, then the Russo-Dye Theorem implies that $\|\phi\|=\|\phi(1)\|$, from where it immediately
follows that
$$
  \|\phi\| =  \sup\big \{\|\phi(a)\|: a\geq 0,\ \|a\|\leq 1\big \}.
  \tag 1
  $$

**Question**.  Is (1) still valid in case $A$ is non-unital?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: The consequence of the Russo-Dye Theorem I am referring to may itself be proved by means of Cauchy-Schwartz-like
inequalities (see Theorems 1.3.1(ii) and 1.3.3 in Erling Størmer's book "Positive Linear Maps of Operator Algebras"),
but since these maps are not scalar valued, Cauchy-Schwartz is not as straightforward and often requires the elements
involved to be normal.  In fact there are open problems regarding whether or not these hold for hyponormal elements (see
M.-D. Choi, Some assorted inequalities for positive linear maps on C$^*$-algebras. J. Oper.  Theory 4(2), 271–285
(1980)).

Comment: Is that what you have in your mind?  If so, it would be helpful should you be able to explain your argument
with some more detail.

Comment: Black: I assume @MikaeldelaSalle is referring to the usual CS inequality in $H$, and the fact that you can calculate the norm of $\phi(b)$ as the norm of an operator. Also the formula $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,T^*y \rangle$ looks like it should be useful.

Comment: (In this case, it seems that the Russo-Dye theorem is a red herring, or overkill)

Comment: @YemonChoi, Well, I definitely do not think Russo-Dye is an overkill, and I think Størmer agrees, given his proof of Theorem 1.3.3.
I think I now have a proof based on extending $\phi$ to the unitization of $A$, but I was hoping to find a one-liner,
possibly based on Cauchy-Schwartz, as mentioned by Mikael.  Yes, I know that $\|\phi(b)\|$ is the norm of an operator
and that that $\langle Tx, y\rangle  = \langle x, T^*y\rangle $, but still I cannot see how to get the conclusion from Cauchy-Schwartz.  Would you be
so kind as to give further details?

Comment: @Black I am sorry, I misread your question and I thought that the assumption was that $\varphi$ is completely positive. And (as you observe in the comments), then the validity of (1) is indeed a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @Black My bad: I made the same misreading as Mikael. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments,  I'm hoping to find a one-liner based on Cauchy-Schwartz,  as suggested by user  Mikael
de la Salle.  However, while this is not
available,  let me present a proof I just found based on extending $\phi$ to the unitization of $A$.
Let
$$
  S = \sup\big \{\|\phi(a)\|: a\geq 0,\ \|a\|\leq 1\big \},
  $$
and let
$\Phi $ be the extension of $\phi$ to the unitization $\tilde A$ defined by setting $\Phi (1)=SI_H$.

I claim that $\Phi $ is positive.  To see this we must check that
$$
  \Phi \big ((a-\lambda 1)^*(a-\lambda 1)\big )\geq 0,
  \tag{$\star$}
  $$
for every $a$ in $A$, and every $\lambda \in {\mathbb C}$.  The case $\lambda =0$ is clearly true, so we may assume that $\lambda \neq 0$.   In the latter
case, we may change variables by replacing $a$ with $\lambda a$, and then
divide everithing by $|\lambda |^2$, leading to the following equivalent form  of $(\star)$:
$$
  \Phi \big ((a-1)^*(a-1)\big )\geq 0,
  \tag{$\star\star$}
  $$
Observing that
$$
  0\leq (a-1)^*(a-1) = a^*a-a^*-a+1,
  $$
and fixing an approximate identity $\{u_i\}_i$ for $A$, we have for all $i$ that
$$
  u_i(a^*+a -a^*a)u_i \leq  u_i^2,
  $$
so
$$
  \phi\big (u_i(a^*+a -a^*a)u_i\big ) \leq  \phi(u_i^2) \leq  \|\phi(u_i^2)\|I_H \leq  SI_H = \Phi (1).
  $$
Taking the limit as $i\to \infty $, the above yields
$$
  \phi (a^*+a -a^*a) \leq  \Phi (1),
  $$
which is equivalent to $(\star\star)$, proving the claim.

By [1, Theorem 1.3.3], (which Størmer proves using Russo-Dye and Cauchy-Schwartz),
we then deduce that
$$
  S = \|\Phi (1)\| = \|\Phi \| \geq  \|\phi\| \geq  S,
  $$
concluding the proof.

[1] Størmer, Erling, Positive linear maps of operator algebras,  Springer 2013.